# is there a way to examine if an angle is a right angle programmatically?

Tags: python, computational-geometry

i plot an angle in python

[image: i]

here is the code

```
x = [0,0.5,1]
y = [0,0.5,0]
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

is there a way to examine if the angle is a right angle programmatically?

Comment: Yes, you can find the angle between 3 points `(0.0,0.0),(0.5,0.5),(1.0,0.0)`. Maybe take a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361412/finding-the-angle-between-three-points

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, there is.

```
x = [0,0.5,1]
y = [0,0.5,0]
points = [np.array(point) for point in zip(x,y)]
a, b, c = points
ba = a - b
bc = c - b
cosine_angle = np.dot(ba, bc) / (np.linalg.norm(ba) * np.linalg.norm(bc))
angle_rad = np.arccos(cosine_angle)
angle_deg = np.rad2deg(angle_rad)
print(angle_deg) # 90.0
```

Comment: Note that `np.dot(ba, bc)` is equal to 0 when b is a right angle. You don't need to compute the angle itself (or the norm of the vectors).

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to test if the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of the vectors is 0.

In your case, you simply compute:

```
v1 = ( (x[1]-x[0]), (y[1]-y[0]) ) <- (0.5, 0.5)
v2 = ( (x[2]-x[1]), (y[2]-y[1]) ) <- (0.5, -0.5)

dot_product = v1[0]*v2[0] + v1[1]*v2[1] <- 0.5² - 0.5² = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to calculate the angle, but an easier way could be to check whether the Pythagorean Theorem applies. For that you'll need to calculate the size of the three edges and then check whether `A^2 + B^2 ~= C^2`

Comment: The three surfaces ?

Comment: Three edges. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers do not really care about possible inaccuracies and truncation errors, nor efficiency.

Rather than an exact comparison to 90° (or 0° in case of dot product), it is wiser to check for a small angle difference to 90° (resp. 0°).

Also wise to avoid divisions, square roots and trigonometric functions. The cross-product method is among the most attractive.

Compute the cross-product of the sides of the angle and their squared lengths, and compare
with a precomputed tolerance:

```
(ABx . BCy - ABy . BCx)² ≥ α.(ABx² + ABy²).(BCx² + BCy²)
```

with `α = cos²δ` where `δ` is the angle tolerance.

Comment: thanks! is there a guidance about setting the value of δ ?

Comment: @singularli: this depends on the quality of your data and your application.

Comment: That s a fair point. Using floating point number you cannot guarantee the vector are orthogonals. In this case, I guess we would move to fractional arithmetic.

Comment: @MichaelDoubez: what do you mean by *fractional arithmetic* ?

Comment: Sorry, I mean rational number arithmetic: restricting the vectors to be expressed in Q and use [fractions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html) module.

Comment: I do use floating in my paid job but the range of values is known and we can make it work. In the case of determining is vectors are orthogonals, you could claim that a computer cannot give 100% accuracy if you have non exact representation. Even with epsilon comparison as you propose, you may end up with false positives.

Answer (score -1):

You can compute the angle between the two vectors as following: first, get the two vectors `v1` and `v2` and then use `np.arccos()` which returns the angle in radians. Convert it to degrees to check if it is 90 degrees. The formulae for computing angle between two vectors can be found on this [Wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition)

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0,0.5,1])
y = np.array([0,0.5,0])

vecs = np.vstack((x, y))
v1 = vecs[:, 1] - vecs[:, 0]
v2 = vecs[:, 2] - vecs[:, 1]

angle_rad = np.arccos(np.dot(v1, v2) / (np.linalg.norm(v1) * np.linalg.norm(v2)))

angle_deg = np.rad2deg(angle_rad)
# 90.0
```